# Should I worry about a siphon with my sump pump?

Tags: sump-pump

I live in a typical suburban home. My sump pump discharges water up from the beneath the slab about 9 feet and moves outside through the rim joist. The pipe then turns into the ground and joins the downspout drain line out to the street.

Do I need to worry about water siphoning back into the basement after a pump cycle during a flood event where the street is filled with water, over the drain line exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output pipe should contain a one-way valve not far from the pump.  Otherwise, your 9 foot column of water would drain back into the sump bucket when the pump shuts off.  This also prevents any siphoning when the pump isn't running.

Comment: Are any check valves truly 100% water tight?

Comment: @EvilElf, they're designed to be water-tight.  There is also the weight of the 9 foot column of water pushing it closed.

Comment: The weight of the water column is a good point.